# What is best online Archival site not backups for big personal data

Tags: backup, storage, cloud

I am looking for online site where i can upload / Archive my data so that i can browse from web to have a look at what i have and in case i need it somewhere else then i can download it.

I don't want backups services like `livedrive`, `crashplan` , `mozy`, `justcloud` where they are only linked to one computer and i can't upload files to my one account from different computers

I have around 1TB of data which i want to host on web.

I like `Google Docs` but its very costly for 1TB, s3 is also very costly.

The only option i currently see is `Adrive`. But is there any other site which can do what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the cloud storage sites offer you a free storage space aroud 10gb , but [Mega](https://mega.co.nz/)
initially offers a free storage of 50 GB.Or if you're willing to pay, you can get infinite storage for $99/yr from  [Bitcasa Infinite Drive](https://www.bitcasa.com/).

Or you can roll out your own personal storage service with [OwnCloud](http://owncloud.org/).This article [here](http://lifehacker.com/5993596/how-to-set-up-your-own-private-cloud-storage-service-in-five-minutes-with-owncloud) will help you setup one.

Comment: thanks buddy bitcasa is what i want. dont trust `Mega` dont know if its like `Megupload` they can stop anytime

Comment: Well, [Bitcasa changed their business model](http://blog.bitcasa.com/2014/10/23/important-we-are-upgrading-storage-infrastructure-and-need-you-to-take-action/). I would NOT recommend their services at all anymore (if only as they failed to notify me about their changes, and wiped my data).